# Delete multiple lines from a text file in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a program that reads multiple lines from a text file and it works fine. What I was trying to add to it was the functionality to delete the read lines after displaying it. Is there any way in js to delete those lines like a remove method? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```js
let getLines = function getLines(filename, lineCount, callback) {
  let stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
    flags: "r",
    encoding: "utf-8",
    fd: null,
    mode: 438, // 0666 in Octal
    bufferSize: 64 * 1024
  });

  let data = "";
  let lines = [];
  stream.on("data", function(moreData) {
    data += moreData;
    lines = data.split("\n");
    // probably that last line is "corrupt" - halfway read - why > not >=
    if (lines.length > lineCount + 1) {
      stream.destroy();
      lines = lines.slice(0, lineCount); // junk as above
      callback(false, lines);
    }
  });

  stream.on("error", function() {
    callback("Error");
  });

  stream.on("end", function() {
    callback(false, lines);
  });

};

getLines("filePath", 10, function(err, lines) {
  console.log(lines) //display the read lines then..
  //delete the read 10 line here
});
```

Comment: The common way to solve this problem is to write all lines you don't want to delete into an new temporary file and overwrite the old file with the new file.